# AppKit: How can I remove one pixel inset of NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, appkit

I'm totally new to AppKit. I'm so confused about managing layout of AppKit views.

I have a view which frame is 450*300

[image]

and I added an outline view in the view but it has one pixel inset automatically added.

[image]

This makes a one pixel border and it makes me annoying.

I can't fix it at all. There's no options about insets, constraints and resizing frame. What I wanna do is just making outline view's size the same as the super view's size so that there's no tiny border.

Comment: Did you select the the scroll view, the clip view or the outline view? Do you need a superview if it's the same size? If you don't want the border then set the Border Type of the scroll view to None.

Comment: @Willeke That's what I exactly look for. As your expectation, I clicked the clipview to show there's offset x:1, y:1. I realized I don't need any superview to show outline view. Thanks a lot!